# Are these maps group homomorphisms?

Tags: finite-groups, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group, $M$ a trivial $G$-module and let $f:G \times G \to M$ be a 2-cocycle.

**Question:** Are the following maps $f_1,f_2$ group homomorphisms ?

$$f_1: G \to M,\; g \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{|G|}f(g,g^i)$$
$$f_2: G \to M,\; g \mapsto \sum_{h\in G}f(g,h)$$

Comment: Please indicate you have made some effort to solve the problem yourself. It's usually better to ask a question that helps you to understand the problem, rather than asking the problem itself.

Comment: At the moment, it's not clear you even understand the problem, so one can only guess how to answer it in a way that's useful. Do you know what a cocycle is? etc.

Comment: Ben, I posted a well-formulated question. A qualified answer gives either a proof that $f_i$ is a group homomorphism or provides a counterexample. I feel statements like "it's not clear you even understand the problem" or "do you know what a cocycle is ?"  humiliating. Please be polite. Thanks.

Comment: Well @user63850, you may have a point there, yet if you'd add some explanation, ideas, insights to your question, which is *not* basic mathematics and thus, one assumes, is asked by at least an advanced undergraduated, no one will be able to ask you those questions...

Comment: I'm sorry, my intention was not to humiliate. But I feel like you're expecting more effort on the part of the answerer than you've provided yourself, and I don't think that's fair. I have no trouble believing that you understand the problem – you might be extremely intelligent. But you've not *shown* that, so I don't know what it is that you need explaining. If you'd spend a bit more time explaining why you are asking this question and why you can't answer it yourself, it would encourage much better answers.

Comment: (As it happens, I don't know what a cocycle is! But I'm frustrated by the number of people who treat this site as somewhere to get free work done for you in exchange for no reward.)

Comment: I think this is a good question. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, no. Take an arbitrary map $\alpha:G\to M$. Then $f(g,h)=\alpha(g)-\alpha(gh)+\alpha(h)$ is a cocycle which does not satisfy your conditions.

Comment: Good answer. Thank you.